# Cannot convert canvas to image when there is another image in it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to export Raphael -> PNG.  I actually had to write my own function to parse the DOM objects.

My canvas works but the conversion using toDataUrl() doesn't always work.  I've come to see that if there is an image on the canvas so the canvas does not export, otherwise it does.

Is anyone familiar with this?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is the image on the canvas from another domain?

Comment: yes it is on another domain

Comment: Then you have a tainted canvas, you can't get a data url from a tainted canvas.

Comment: no even if it's on the same domain, even if it's on my computer in the same directory still doesn't work